# How much internal storage for apps does Nexus 4 have?

Tags: internal-storage, nexus-4

Please tell me that 16GB of internal storage as mentioned on NEXUS 4 is available for apps or for apps it creates separate internal storage thing as it does in Nexus S...

Comment: The internal storage space on a Nexus 4 may be prove to be a disappointment to many especially with the lack of a microSD card. Apparently USB OTG Connectivity would solve this greatly. It is supposedly supported, however connectivity as far as i'm aware has yet to be established. I wrote a post on the internal storage dilemma here http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34348/lg-nexus-4s-internal-storage-dilemma-its-apparent-lack-of-support-for-usb-otg#comment44535_34348

Comment: Since the Galaxy Nexus, it's been unified to a single partition that grows uniformly whether you install apps or shoot photographs: http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/11/18/impromptu-qa-session-with-android-engineer-dan-morrill-brings-to-light-reasons-behind-galaxy-nexus-lack-of-usb-mass-storage/

Answer (score 4):

No device can have all of its internal storage free for user. The Operating System (and pre-installed apps) needs some space for itself. So Nexus 4 doesn't give you 16 GB free either.

The **16 GB** version of Nexus 4 gives user an approximate of **12.92 GB** free. Whereas, the **8 GB** version of Nexus 4 gives you an approximate of **5.67 GB** free space to use.

I don't have the device (at least yet). This is what I have found in reviews / discussions.

Comment: I wonder; Why the used internal storage is not consistent? i.e. The 16 GB version ships with 3.08 GBs taken up by the OS. While the 8 GB version ships with 2.33 GBs taken up.

Answer (score 1):

I have a 16Gb Nexus 4 and I can report that settings -> storage indicates a total capacity of 12.92Gb. There does not appear to be any  restriction on how this is used. It's possible that there is some hidden limit, but if so there is no indication of such. It seems very likely that you can install as many Gb of apps as you can fit on there :-)